# Bootstrap Navbar Buttons Getting Mixed Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Navbar that works fine in desktop but when shrunk down at about 425px the contact button starts to work as the login button as well, which it's never have done before.

The code I have is this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav navtop navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Contact Us <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/business-advertising">Advertising</a></li>
      <li><a href="/council-contact">Contact the Council </a></li>
      <li><a href="/report-a-problem">Report a Problem</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <p class="modalfooter discoverthesecret">discover the secret...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So when I click on the contact us, it loads up the login modal?

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me? https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/ORedyM

Comment: Where do I have to click ... ?

Comment: If you go onto the mobile version, then click on the menu.. then if you click on contact us it'll load up the login form as apposed to the dropdown that it is meant to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second list item (login btn) is over the first so you are triggering the the second instead of first

add the following:

```
.nav>li {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Will accept it as answer when I can.

Comment: glad i can help :)

Comment: Only issue is now that on the tabs it also halves them? Is there a way to only make this affect the navbar?

Comment: use another selector like .navbar-nav>li and media querys to limit your css to small screens only

Comment: Works perfectly now, thank you. Accepted as answer :)